# How to get easyui datebox content if it is placed inside Iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, jquery-easyui, datebox

I tried with the below code to access easyui datebox content placed inside Iframe and it doesn't succeed.

```
alert($("#documentFrame").contents().find("#field6").datebox('getValue');
```

Where `#documentFrame` is Iframe ID and `#field6` ID if the datebox.

Getting the value of text boxes is working fine with the following code.

```
alert($("#documentFrame").contents().find("#field2").val());
```

Where `#documentFrame` is Iframe ID and `#field2` ID if the inputbox.

How could I to get datebox value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish the process of getting datebox content which is placed inside Iframe you can follow this:

You need to write function as below in your iframe document which returns datebox value.

**Code**

```
function getValue(value){
    var id='#'+value;
    var val= $(id).datebox('getValue');
    return val;
}
```

From parent document you can call getValue() method and pass datebox component ID as argument to the getValue() method.

**Code to call getValue() from Iframe parent document**

```
value = window.frames[0].getValue('field ID');
alert(value);
```

Thank you